# When trying to open Tor, I'm getting this error message

Tags: help

I'm new to this, so sorry if this is a stupid question and/or an easy fix. I just can't seem to find any information that helps with this issue anywhere. Whenever I go to open Tor, I'm getting this error message:

The item 'firefox.exe' which this shortcut refers to has been changed or moved, so this shortcut will no longer work properly. Do you want to delete this shortcut?

Everything was working fine until about April of this year, when I started getting this error message. I've tried to uninstall and reinstall multiple times but that hasn't worked. Also, Tor is not even showing up in my 'programs' list when I do have it installed. Maybe it's a bug, or something? I've looked into restoring broken shortcuts but nothing I've found has helped. Again, sorry if this is stupid. If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So what happened on april? Anything you might have installed that could be causing an issue? Do you have a restoration point? Have you done any initial research on the TOR docs so that we can know a bit more of your background?

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstall it, you will be told where it being installed. Go to that folder and run firefox.exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your shortcut is not pointing to `firefox.exe` anymore which is the file that starts Tor, speed fix: just do a search for `firefox.exe`, find the file with a small purple dot followed by `firefox.exe` double click it, done

`Tor is not even showing up in my 'programs' list when I do have it installed`

That's totally normal, Tor does not show up there